# adding value to shoping cart via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the item to cart by clicking on the item like div class box2 i have demo item when i click on the image i get the name and the price but the name and price is not adding to ul class add please help me out how can i get the values from image and set into the cart

```
 <div class="box2">
              <p>pkr 700.0</p>
               <img src="images/col.png" />
               <h1>Beverges</h1>
    </div>

    <ul class="add">
              <li>bellle belle belle 25cl
                 <p>2 Unit(s) at PKR 0.8/Unit(s)</p>
              </li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.box2').click(function(){
          var price=$(".box2 p:first").html();
          var product=$(".box2 h1:first").html();
          $(".add li:first").val(product);
          $(".add li p:first").val(price);
          alert(price);
          alert(product);
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [text method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [html method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of val method:

```
$(".add li:first").text(product);
$(".add li p:first").text(price);
```

Or,

```
$(".add li:first").html(product);
$(".add li p:first").html(price);
```

val() method is only for input element types.

---

You are assigning two values to same element which will override, so use like this:

```
$(".add li:first").text(product + " " + price);
```

**Update:** As per comment [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48mrz/1/)

```
$('.box2').click(function(){
          var price=$(".box2 p:first").html();
          var product=$(".box2 h1:first").html();
    $(".add li:first").contents().filter(function(){
       return this.nodeType == 3;  
    })[0].nodeValue = product;
    $(".add li:first p").text(price);
      });
```

Comment: let me check and also can i add some custom text or remove the text from selected values

Comment: the first one is working $(".add li:first").text(product); but the second one is not working please check it what i have done wrong with this one $(".add li p:first").text(price);

Comment: but in my case i have <ul><li><p></p></li></ul> so it mean ul li:first and ul li p:first am i right

Comment: oh! sorry, then do like this: $(".add li:first p").text(price);

Comment: no the price is not coming up only the name is showing  in your js fiddle too

Comment: can you modify your html?

Comment: Thankyou boss for giving me your precious time

Comment: now another problem arise i have many item with the same class name but when i click on any item it collect the values of first item i am going to post the question please check out

Comment: please check out this question click returns only the first item value in jquery

Answer (score 0):

`List item(li)` is not an `input type control` so `val()` will not work here try using `text()` instead

```
$(".add li:first").text("some text here");
$(".add li p:first").text("some text here");
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` and `li` doesnt have  `val()`

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box2').click(function(){
      var price=$(".box2 p:first").html();
      var product=$(".box2 h1:first").html();
      $(".add li:first").html(product);
      $(".add li p:first").html(price);
      alert(price);
      alert(product);
  });
});
```